# Regex in a redirect source is causing an infinite loop when string is repeated in target

Tags: regex, redirect

Currently experiencing an infinte loop with a redirect implemented

Here is an example:

```
Source https://www.example.com/destinations/(.*)
Target https://www.example.com/blog/travel/destinations
```

But if I have a redirect with higher prority

```
Source https://www.example.com/destinations/japan
Target https://www.example.com/blog/travel/destinations/japan
```

The output is as follows

```
https://www.example.com/blog/travel/https:/www.example.com/blog/travel/https:/www.example.com/blog/travel/https:/www.example.com/blog/travel/https:/www.example.com/blog/travel.....
```

Which is causing an infinite loop due to the second instance of `/destinations/`

Is there anyway to use a regular expresion to only look for `/destinations/` once and ignore any other instances.

I've tried a negative look ahead to no avail `(?!.*\/destinations\/)`

I need the catch all regex to function correctly with other uses of `/destinations/` not to cause redirect infinte loops

Comment: what system? It's not obvious how `a/d/b -> a/c/d` and `a/d/e -> a/c/d/e` can loop as rhs is not contained in lhs